# CSS Rule for the 8th and on element in a div

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to create a CSS rule that applies to the every element except for the first 8 elements? Ie, the 8th plus elements should have a margin top of 65px.

My below less code applies margins to every odd and even button within a menu. Now I want to add a specific margin to the 8th plus buttons. And then ideally apply a specific margin to the 16th plus buttons and so on.

```
.foo-menu {

    .foo-menu-btn {
        float: left;
        margin: 1px;
    }

    // Apply specific margin to every second(even) button 
    .foo-menu-btn:nth-child(even) {
        margin-left: -23px;
        margin-top: 46px;
    }

    // Apply specific margin to every odd button 
    .foo-menu-btn:nth-child(odd) {
        margin-left: -23px;
    }

    // For every button after the 8th one; apply a specific margin
    .foo-menu-btn:nth-child( ??? ) {
        margin-top: 65px;
    }
}



<div class="foo-menu">

    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>

    <!-- Now every foo-menu-btn should have a top margin of 65px -->
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native CSS [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class to specify a range. According to the case you specified it might look like this:

```
div.foo-menu div.foo-menu-btn:nth-child(n+8):nth-child(-n+15) {
      margin-left: 50px
}
```

The downside is that you still have to manually define each range.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, i think help full to you.

```css
hr {
    display: block; float: left;
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    border: solid 2px #aaa; margin: 10px;
}

hr:nth-child(n+9):not(:nth-last-child(-n)) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id=t>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select everything other than the first 8 divs you can use `.foo-menu-btn:nth-child(n+9)`. See it applied to your HTML below (I took out the negative margins so that the divs would be visible for this example):

```css
.foo-menu-btn {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1rem;
}

.foo-menu-btn:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: 46px;
}

.foo-menu-btn:nth-child(n+9) {
    margin-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo-menu">

    <div class="foo-menu-btn">1</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">2</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">3</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">4</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">5</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">6</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">7</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">8</div>

    <!-- Now every foo-menu-btn should have a top margin of 65px -->
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">9</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">10</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">11</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">12</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">13</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">14</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">15</div>
    <div class="foo-menu-btn">16</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
.foo-menu .foo-menu-btn:nth-child(n+9){
    color: blue;
}
```

```css
.foo-menu .foo-menu-btn:nth-child(odd){
  color: red;
}

.foo-menu .foo-menu-btn:nth-child(even){
  color: green;
}

.foo-menu .foo-menu-btn:nth-child(n+9){
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo-menu">

  <div class="foo-menu-btn">1</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">2</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">3</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">4</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">5</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">6</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">7</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">8</div>

    <!-- Now every foo-menu-btn should have a top margin of 65px -->
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">9</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">10</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">11</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">12</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">13</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">14</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">15</div>
  <div class="foo-menu-btn">16</div>
</div>
```